# How to add a Cocoapod dependency to a Cocoapod?

Tags: cocoapods

I have created a Cocoapod with `pod lib create <MYPOD>`.  I basically want this Pod to be a class that utilizes Google Maps and provides some extra functionality.  I have no idea how to do this.  The folder structure of the created Pod project is confusing.  The pod file sits in an examples folder.  When I try to install a GoogleMaps pod by adding `target '<MYPOD>' pod 'GoogleMaps' end` I get an error: `Unable to find a target named``, did find '<MYPOD>_Tests'.`

Answer (score 3):

In your Podspec file add

`s.dependency = 'GoogleMaps'`

While doing `pod lib lint` use `pod lib lint --use-libraries` instead

Comment: Do I have to run something after adding this to get the dependency to load for development?

Comment: Got it... `pod update` in the sample project directory

Comment: `--use-libraries` did the trick for me. It also helped with `pod spec lint` and `pod trunk push`